# Git: pushed a file that should not be tracked

Tags: git

What should I do if I push a file  to a remote repository that should not be tracked? For instance, [Intellij IDEA has a file name `workspace.xml` in `.idea` folder which should not be tracked by git.](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839-How-to-manage-projects-under-Version-Control-Systems)

---

Situation

1. I have added `workspace.xml`, committed and pushed.
2. My team may or may not have pulled that commit yet.
3. The wrong commit is not the latest commit in remote repository now.

---

What is the best way to untrack the `workspace.xml` with least loss?

I can figure out some ways but they all have some shortcoming:

1. Ask people in team to use `git update-index --skip-worktree workspace.xml`. This way makes everybody do one thing which I think is not good.
2. Submit a new commit in which use `git rm --cached` to delete `workspace.xml` in index but not my local repository. This way makes everybody in team lose their own local file `workspace.xml` once they merge my new commit.

Is there any good way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

git revert your commit

You will need to have your teammates who have already are upstream from your commit to do a git pull --rebase

This will pull your commit out and not squash other people's workspace.xml

And then listen to sajib and add .idea to your .gitignore